# Process for resolving error messages in NEXTGIS

Tags: qgis-2.18, nextgis

I'm uplifting a map to NEXTGIS and I get the errors:

Response status code is 502
{"exception": "ValidationError", "message": "GDAL library was unable to open the file.", "attr": "source", "serializer": "raster_layer"}

What do these mean?
How do I resolve the problem?
What is the general procedure for resolving any error messages from NEXTGIS uploads?
[image]

Comment: Time to act, [@Dmitry Baryshnikov](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/9904/dmitry-baryshnikov) =)

Comment: I do not understand what this means.

Comment: @IanGS can you describe the steps to reproduce (better is to update topic)? As I see screenshot is not from QGIS. Do you try to load your raster file via administrative web interface? Also, sample raster will helpful - can you share it on support@nextgis.com?

Comment: @Dmitry Baryshnikov - yes it is from QGIS - its the error box/window. Both files are shapefiles.

Comment: Can you share the whole QGIS project include shape files and rasters on support@nextgis.com? It seems that this connected with some basemap in your project but I want to sure.

Comment: Just sent you 2 emails with appropriate files and download links. Is this sufficient/adequate?

Comment: @IanGS Yes, I got everything needed to reproduce this error. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reducing amount of data and repeat again. I've tried your test project and smaller shapefile (100 first features from your test Shapefile) - all worked fine.

**Disclaimer**: I'm developer at NextGIS.